# Thread variable after call start and run

Tags: java, multithreading

I realized that this code:

```
public class TestThread3 extends Thread {

    private int i;
    public void run() {
         i++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestThread3 a  = new TestThread3();
        a.run();
        System.out.println(a.i);
        a.start();
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
```

results in `1 1` printed ... and i don't get it.  I haven´t found information about how to explain this.  Thanks.

Comment: Try using a.join() after a.start().  I think your program is calling the second print and completing before the other thread gets the CPU to run.  This causes a potential Race Condition.  If you want the order of execution to be guaranteed, you need to Synchronize them somehow.  But for an instance like this,you likely shouldn't be using threads since you are concerned with the order of execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> results in 1 1 printed

So the first `a.run();` is called by the main-thread directly by calling the `a.run()` method.  This increments `a.i` to be 1.  The call to `a.start();` then is called which actually forks a new thread.  However, this takes time to do so the `i++;` operation most likely has not started before the `System.out.println(...)` call is made so `a.i` is still only 1.  Even if the `i++` *has* completed in the `a` thread *before* the `println` is run, there is nothing that causes the `a.i` field to be synchronized between the `a` thread and the main-thread.

If you want to *wait* for the spawned thread to finish then you need to do a `a.join();` call before the call to `println`.  The `join()` method ensures that memory updates done in the `a` thread are visible to the thread calling join.  Then the `i++` update will be seen by the main-thread.  You could also use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a `int` which wraps a `volatile int` and provides memory synchronization.  However, without the `join()` there is still a race condition between the `a` thread doing the increment and the `println`.

```
// this provides memory synchronization with the internal volatile int
private AtomicInteger i;
...
public void run() {
   i.incrementAndGet();
}
...
a.start();
// still a race condition here so probably need the join to wait for a to finish
a.join();
System.out.println(a.i.get());
```

Comment: Sure ... thats the point! ... the time required to create the new thread ... thanks.

Comment: AND the memory synchronization @Rafael.

Comment: Even if you put a `Thread.sleep(100)` in main before the `println`, it may still print `1` @Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can change at any point of time because when a.start() is called, the thread is scheduled for process, not necessary the OS will let it start executing on CPU.

Once a.start() returns, you actually have two threads (one is for main and another is a new thread), and the main would still be running.

The expected result could only come if following happens,

Time

T1 main method calls a.start()

T2 jvm / os schedules thread for execution

T3 a.start() returns and main thread gets context-switched and suspended for other threads.

T4 Spawned thread gets execution context, and its run method is called, which increments value

T5 context switch happens and main thread gets the control back

T6 main thread would print 2

Jatan

Comment: This isn't taking into account memory synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main issues here to clear up.  I also recommend you examine [Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray)'s answer for more technical information.

**Note:  This just skims the surface, but most of the other answers take for granted the background knowledge on these Computer Science topics that I believe you have not yet mastered.

First, threads are not guaranteed order of execution.  In general, you should only use threads if they can work asynchronously (independently timed).  For this example, you have a timing-specific expected outcome, so threading should probably just be avoided.

This, however, isn't your only issue.

As is, your code also has what is called a Race Condition.  A Race Condition occurs when two different threads (or processes) have access to read/manipulate the same data -- In your case, reading `i` and incrementing via `i++`.

For example,

Imagine that you and a friend both have a dollar.  The Ice Cream Man drives along and stops in front of you.  The Ice Cream Man only has one ice cream cone left.  There are a couple of ways this could play out:

1. You are faster than your friend and buy the cone first.
2. You are slower than your friend and he buys the cone first.
3. You decide to split the ice cream cone and both pay $0.50.
4. You two fight and someone else gets to buy the last ice cream cone while you two are distracted.

To mirror this back to the computer,

1. The main thread where you are printing continues to run even after you started the second thread.  (Threads are linked to the same process, so when main returns, the other threads "die".  It is possible the thread, even though it a.start()'ed, doesn't finish or may not even get a chance to run at all!)
2. The other thread gets to run and completes before returning to the main thread.
3. You take turns executing and everyone gets to do a few lines of code.  The out come is really asynchronous here.  And this can very likely happen.
4. The java application process loses the CPU and someone else gets to run (potentially accessing similar shared information.)

TL;DR -

If you want to ensure execution order, then just DO NOT use threads.

There are some cases where syncing up at certain points along the way would be nice.  For these cases, you can join the threads (wait for one to finish before continuing), or lock the Race Condition with a Mutex or Semaphore (more advanced synchronization techniques).

I recommend doing some reading on these topics before attempting to jump into battle with the monstrous operating system.